# Outlook VBA: How to get 'To' first name?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba

I can get email 'To' recipient full name with below code.

```
Set oMItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
recip = oMItem.To
```

How to get only first name directly?

Note: In some system, it shows last name first, it's not safe to use left().

Comment: Assuming the To address is in the format forename.surname; you'll want some regex or use a `=left()` picking up the `.` between forename.surname as the split.

Comment: Are you using exchange account? If so, based on my research,we could use "ExchangeUser.FirstName", for more information, you could refer to this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048701/extract-first-name-of-the-sender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code can get first recipient's first name.

```
Dim oMItem As Outlook.MailItem

   Select Case TypeName(Application.ActiveWindow)
      Case "Explorer"
         Set oMItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
      Case "Inspector"
         Set oMItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
      Case Else
   End Select

recip = oMItem.Recipients.Item(1).AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.FirstName
```

Comment: Are you saying it can work for you ?

Comment: If it could work for you, it would be better to mark it to an answer.